# Amazon SES and Apple private relay bounce

Tags: cloudflare, amazon-ses, apple, plesk

When I send emails to Apple private relay addresses,they always bounce when sending via Amazon ses. No other emails have this problem.

I have SPF DKIM and DMARC all configured correctly. But Amazon doesn’t allow me to configure an exact email address as the Mail From address, instead I can only configure a Mail From domain.

This is where I run into problems I think. Amazon uses the Mail From domain, but then prepends a UUID to the Mail From address. eg my Mail From domain is: mydomain.com

and the actual Mail From address generated by Amazon will be something like: random_uuid@mydomain.com

in my Apple developer account I have added mydomain.com, and the actual email address I use to send from. For example: news@mydomain.com

But because Amazon randomises the Mail From address for every email sent, I have no way of registering the email with Apple and it bounces…

My server setup is Ubuntu 20.04, Postfix, Dovecote, Plesk Obsidian. And I also use Cloudlare.

is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Kinda silly oversight really. I had set up my MAIL FROM domain in Amazon as `mail.blah.com` but in Apple I was only verifying `email@blah.com`

As soon as I added `email@mail.blah.com` the emails were delivered.